# Keeping the dimension of the matrix but finding values greater than 0.1, and putting them in new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

i have a small problem.
i have a 3D matrix, and i want to seperate values greater than 0.1 into a new matrix, but keep the dimentions intact.. Because it is 24x45x65. and 24 = hours, 45 = days and 65 = customers.
is it possible? i used `find()` no luck..i used `x_weekday(x_weekday > 0.1)` i get the values greater than 0.1 but all in 1 column..and it destroys the dimention.

help please.

i have attached the file as link if need be.
file: [x_weekday.mat](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/11579/x_weekday.mat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1:

```
%%// new_x_weekday would be the one you are after, assuming you want to 
%%// keep the rest of the data that are not greater than 0.1 to be 0

new_x_weekday = zeros(size(x_weekday))
new_x_weekday(x_weekday>0.1) = x_weekday((x_weekday>0.1))
```

Approach 2:

```
new_x_weekday = x_weekday;
new_x_weekday(new_x_weekday<=0.1)=0
```

Comment: yes this works thanks...Do u also know how to solve this: 
since the matrix is: 24x45x65 and now i took the mean of its row like this: mean(new_matrix,2) and now i get a 24x1x65 matrix..can i return this matrix to a 2D matrix now. :) thanks again

Comment: Use  -`squeeze` to remove singleton dimensions, which is the second dimension in your case. Thus - `squeeeze(mean(new_matrix,2))`

Comment: Hi again. the code u gave me the one on aproach 2. new_x_weekday<=0.1 etc. it works but when i add: & new_x_weekday>=5 it doesnt do anything.
how can it be? because i want values between 0.1 and 5 in one matrix.

Comment: Use this - `new_x_weekday(new_x_weekday<=0.1 | new_x_weekday>=5)=0`. You needed `OR` there.

Comment: thanks again..sorry for being such a pain :).
the last problem that it causes is that by using any of the approaches i replace the values i dont want with 0. but it will cause problem when i take mean of it..cause mean take the amount and divides it by N. which includes the 0's...is it possible to tell the mean to not include 0's when taking the average?..

Comment: Don't worry about it! Do this - `new_x_weekday(new_x_weekday==0)=NaN` and then `result = nanmean(new_x_weekday)`. Make sure to read doc on `nanmean` if finding mean along different dimensions.